# Nuxt and Bootstrap vue css in html head

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, nuxt.js

For some reason, when I push my project on heroku, bootstrap css in included in the head like so

```
<head>
<title></title>
(..)
<style data-vue-ssr-id="90433b46:0 8b4ab2e8:0 2c8d02e5:0 396e4108:0 01194ca0:0 203df954:0 0323c590:0 5ebbc628:0 7e87bec3:0">/*!
--
  | * Bootstrap v4.1.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
  | * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
  | * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
  | * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
  | */*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}html{font-family:sans-serif;line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-overflow-style:scrollbar;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent
(..)
```

Am I doing something wrong here??

I have NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION set to true and NODE_ENV set to production already.

The way I include it is same as the docs

```
modules: [
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/axios',

(...)
```

I understand why this happens when using npm run watch for hot reloading, but **on production** I want to have the css in an external file which will be included like any other css (with the < link > )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `extractCSS` configuration property. See [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#extractcss)

Comment: You are right. Thanks! Is there any way I could only extract the bootstrap css?

Comment: @mauxtin nothing build in. only maybe with customizing\replacing in buld.extend mini-css-extract-plugin with how u exactly want it to be.